# Работа с файлами

Tags: файлы, c++

В общем, через пару часов у меня будет школьная олимпиадка по Си, на которую меня записали насильно. В целом я знаю, что к чему, но там есть обязательное условие: данные брать из файла и результат записывать в файл тоже. Гуглил - огромные маны по работе (изучать нет времени). Прошу вас написать самые основные функции для работы (открытие, чтение, запись и т.д.) с примерчиками. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для работы с файлами понадобится

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Открытый файл описывается структурой FILE. При открытии файла нужно указать режим. В случае ошибки функция возвращает NULL.

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("Izengardjke.txt", "w");
/* r - чтение, файл должен быть
 * w - запись, старое содержимое удаляется, файл создаётся
 * a - дополнение в конец файла, файл создаётся
 * a+ - чтение и дополнение, содержимое сохраняется.
 *      читать можно всё (перемещаться по файлу с помощью
 *      fseek(FILE*, int offset, int origin) или 
 *      rewind(FILE*)), но при попытке записи 
 *      указатель будет перемещаться в конец файла
 */
```

Запись выглядит так:

```
char buffer[] = "Hello, World!";
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
```

Чтение - так:

```
fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
```

И не забудьте закрыть файл.

```
fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: по-моему, в таких случаях лучше использовать fscanf / fprintf

Comment: Для текста - да, я уже воспользовался вашим замечанием :)

Comment: ухты. я где не искал простого руководства по работе с файлами в Си-толком понятного и не нашел.. спс.
ЗЫ
хотя я возможно плохо искал)

Answer (score 3):

Для работы с файлами вам нужна библиотека fstream. Класс fstream является производным классом io как и iostream. Поэтому вы можете использовать все те же функции, что и при вводе-выводе.

```
ifstream f("filename");//создать input-file object тоесть файл ИЗ которого читать  
ofstream f1("filename");//output-file object, файл В который записывать  
char ch;  
f.get(ch);//считать один символ из filename  
f1 << ch; //записать символ в filename
```

Comment: Так ведь олимпиада по С, а не по С++!

Comment: метка [с++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B/) стоит

Comment: А в тексте вопроса - олимпиада по С.

Comment: на мой взгляд у метки приоритет выше

Comment: Олимпиада давно закончилась уже наверное. А то, что варианты и для Си, и для Си++ -- замечательно :)

Answer (score 2):

[Вот](http://www.intuit.ru/department/pl/ccpp/10/) и [вот](http://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.prognull.prognullcpp/200710/29111249.html) - неплохие статьи по теме.

P.S. Ни разу не слышал, чтобы на олимпиадах *требовали* работать с входными/выходными файлами. Обычно на выбор - либо так, либо с потоками ввода/вывода.

Comment: К сожаленью, требуют...

Comment: Там действительно требуют. Условие примерно звучит так: Входной файл: X.in, Выходной файл: X.out предельный размер: 1024КБ.

Comment: @ALEX_LAY_PRO а что за олимпиада, можете сказать?

Comment: Олимпиады по информатике уже давно в подобном духе проходят)) Последний раз был лет 5 назад, задания похожие, правда на них то от информатики и осталось что знание работы с файлом, остальное - составить правильную формулу, но по сути оно и правильно))