# Работа с файлами C++

Tags: файлы, c++

Здравствуйте.

Как создать файл в С++ и, например, записать в нем значение, а после выполнения программы (допустим, там некий цикл) - ответ будет появляться в другом файле? То есть мы вводим данные в 1-й файл, выполняем программу, а ответ будет в другом. Заранее спасибо. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*С учетом, того, что вопрос помечен тэгом `C++`, то отвечу, **как это делается в `C++`, а не в `C`.***

Пусть у вас есть файл с содержимым "25".

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream input("input.in");

    int number;
    input >> number;
    number += 45;

    std::ofstream output("output.out");
    output << number;
}
```

*В таком случае  в выходной файл `output.out` запишется `70`, т.е (`25 + 45`).*

Comment: 2Котик_хочет_кушать, а зачем аругементы для main()?

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов описан в вопросе: [Работа с файлами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37367/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Второй вариант — использование потоков ввода-вывода из стандартной библиотеки iostream. Прочитать про это можно на сайте [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/iostream).